# Add animation during making the pie chart in android using google charts

Tags: javascript, android, charts

I want to add animation in pie chart from zero to given values of the pie chart using google charts. Is it possible in Android? I tried it as

```
function aniChart(d,o){
          for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
            data.setValue(0, 1, i);
          }

          for (var i=99; i>00; i--) {
            data.setValue(1, 1, i);
          }
          setTimeout(function(){
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }, 1000);

        };

        aniChart();
```

Chart is changing its values but not via animation.

**Full HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'ITEM');
      data.addColumn('number', 'VALUE');
      data.addRows([
        ['Item 1', Android.getNum1()],
        ['Item 2', Android.getNum2()],
        ['Item 3', Android.getNum3()],
        ['Item 4', Android.getNum4()],
        ['Item 5', Android.getNum5()]
      ]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'Android-er: Load Google Charts (pie chart) with WebView',
                     'width':600,
                     'height':600
                      };

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

      function aniChart(d,o){
          for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
            data.setValue(0, 1, i);
          }

          for (var i=99; i>00; i--) {
            data.setValue(1, 1, i);
          }
          setTimeout(function(){
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }, 1000);

        };

        aniChart();
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div" style="width:600; height:600"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately, `PieChart` is not listed among the _Valid Chart Types_ for [supported animation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications)...

Comment: @WhiteHat Alright.